# no output from aggregateMessages in GraphFrames

Tags: scala, graphframes

I am just starting with GraphFrames, and though I am following the documentation, I am not able to get any result from the aggregateMessages function (it returns an empty dataframe). Here is a simplified example of my problem: I GraphFrames object called `testGraph` such that my vertexRDD consists of only a single vertex `Y` with no vertex attributes, and my edgeRDD consists of two records like this:

```
| src | dst | min_ts1 | min_ts2 |
|  X  |  Y  |    20   |   null  |
|  Y  |  X  |   null  |   -10   |
```

Now, I want to implement a simple algorithm that sends the value of `min_ts1` to `dst`, and sends `min_ts2` to the `src`. The code I am using to implement this algorithm is :

```
import org.graphframes.lib.AggregateMessages
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val AM = AggregateMessages

val msgToSrc = AM.edge("min_ts2)
val msgToDst = AM.edge("min_ts1")

val delay = testGraph
.aggregateMessages
  .sendToSrc(msgToSrc)
  .sendToDst(msgToDst)  
  .agg(sum(AM.msg).as("avg_time_delay"))
```

I realize there are some null values here, but regardless I would expect the message passing algorithm to do the following: look at the first record, and send a message of `20` to `Y` and a message of `null` to `X`. Then look at the second record, and send a message of `null` to X and a message of `-10` to `Y`. Finally I would expect the result to show that the sum of messages for `Y` is `10`, and for there to be no record for `X` in the result, since it was not included in the vertexRDD. And if `X` were included in the vertexRDD, I would expect the result to be simply `null`, since both of the messages were `null`.

However, what I am getting is an empty RDD. Could someone please help me understand why I am getting an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears that the reason for this issue is indeed that I did not have `X` in my VertexRDD. I guess even if there are edges going to and from that vertex in my edgeRDD and my aggregatemessages depend only on edge attributes, the algorithm is not able to send those messages.